# JGroups VIEW_SYNC gone, which protocol replaces it?

Tags: jgroups

I get this error after upgrading to jgroups-3.4.4.Final.

Sure enough... this class is no longer in the JAR. Unfortunately, I am unclear if I am supposed to just remove this protocol from my jgroups XML, or replace it with a newer/better protocol.. Any advice?

`<VIEW_SYNC avg_send_interval="10000"/>`

`java.lang.Exception: JGRP000002: unable to load protocol VIEW_SYNC (either with relative - VIEW_SYNC - or absolute - org.jgroups.protocols.VIEW_SYNC - class name)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createLayer(Configurator.java:430)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createProtocols(Configurator.java:397)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:88)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:55)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:463)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:824)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:158)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:138)
    at cdot.test.jgroups.TestJGroupsFiles.testJGroupsUDPAsync(TestJGroupsFiles.java:37)`

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to take udp.xml (or tcp.xml if you use TCP as transport) from 3.4.4 (upgrading to 3.4.7 is also recommended), copy it and modify it to match your requirements.
VIEW_SYNC was removed a long time ago and is not needed any longer.
Bela

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks Bela